# Serializing data of li to send by post method ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this snippet

```
<li>
  <a href="#demo_point_in_first_quad" class="btn btn-danger show" data-toggle="collapse">
    Simple collapsible
  </a>

  <div id="demo_point_in_first_quad" class="collapse">
    <label>tts</label> <input id="tts" type="text" value="10"><br>
    <label>topic_level</label> <input id="topic_level" type="text" value="capable"><br>
    <label>to_be_shown_individually</label> <input id="to_be_shown_individually" type="checkbox" checked="">
    <br>
    <label>check_for_geometry</label><input id="check_for_geometry" type="checkbox" checked="">
    <br>
  </div>
</li>
```

And similar to it second li

```
<a href="#demo_point_in_second_quad" class="btn btn-danger show" data-toggle="collapse">
  Simple collapsible
</a>

<div id="demo_point_in_second_quad" class="collapse">
  <label>tts</label> <input id="tts" type="text" value="10"><br>
  <label>topic_level</label> <input id="topic_level" type="text" value="capable"><br>
  <label>to_be_shown_individually</label> <input id="to_be_shown_individually" type="checkbox" checked="">
  <br>
  <label>check_for_geometry</label><input id="check_for_geometry" type="checkbox" checked="">
  <br>
</div>
```

I want the values in the input field to be sent through ajax with there specific div id.

Comment: You may want to wrap the contents in a `form` and then use jQuery's [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method to automatically create form data for submission.

Comment: Yes i have tried it but it is sending all the content inside Div. I just want to send input values

Answer (score 0):

According to your edited question, i would suggest that you add some class to your input elements so that their search becomes easier.

```
<input class="myitem"></input>
```

Then, you can get a list of all inputs as:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("myitem");
```

Finally you can iterate over the list to get the value of inputs

```
for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){
   inputValue = list[i].value; // Value of input field
   parent = list[i].parentElement;  // Parent div has the id so extract from here
   {/* Save both of them somewhere and use as required */}
}


    $.post("url",
      {
        key: value
      },
      function(data){
        alert("Data: " + data);
      });
    });
```

Comment: Yes..i haved made the change in question. As you can see there are diffrent <li> which can be id of anyName coming from Json. So the problem is i want to send all those according to the there ID grouped with data and its value from AJAX on one click.